# Exporting/importing mysql database with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

i'm migrating my website from a shared hosting to a VPS.
I setup all (files, mail, etc) and now i'm migrating database.
In phpmyadmin I export database to my pc, but when i trying to import database in new host (with phpmyadmin) i have only 12 tables of 47. I tried all avaible options, i tried with compression... I checked also table and these are not correctly populated. In the past i do this operation so many time without problem and i don't understand what can be.
Please can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that sometimes PHPMyAdmin has issues with large files. This might be corrected by tweaking PHP's settings in php.ini (extend timeout, raise upload_max_filesize), but it may just be easier to upload the sql file to the server and import it via the command line.

Comment: In addition to this, you might try exporting one table at a time (or at least, one table per file) to see if that improves your situation.